# How to get file of RDD in spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am playing with spark RDD with json files and i am doing something like below

```
val uisJson5 = sqlContext.read.json(
     sc.textFile("s3n://localtion/*")
        .filter(line =>
         line.contains("\"xyz\":\"A\"")
         && line.contains("\"id\":\"adasdfasdfasd\"")
     ))
uisJson5.show()
```

I want to know the source json files as well from where the results are coming. Is there any way i can do this?

Edit:

I was able to do it using below code

```
val uisJson1 = sc.textFile("s3n://localtion/*”) 
.filter(line => line.contains("\"xyz\":\"A\"")
&& line.contains("\"id\":\"adasdfasdfasd\""))

uisJson1.collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `wholeTextFiles` along with `flatMapValues`.

`wholeTextFiles` lets you read a directory containing multiple small text files, and returns each of them as (filename, content) pairs. This is in contrast with textFile, which would return one record per line in each file.

Comment: tried it, got below error  value contains is not a member of (String, String)
                    line.contains("\"xyz\":\"A\"")

Comment: Please post it as an edit to the question and not a comment !

Comment: Yes. Well now you have your file names, but the structure changed, like I said in my answer.